# Module gets reloaded every request so initialized data are lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I store a value in a class variable inside of a module, such as:

```
module TranslationEnhancer
  def self.install! klass
    @dictionaries ||= [] << klass
  end
  ...
end
```

I call this from an initializer in config/initializers:

```
require Rails.root + "lib" + "translation_enhancer.rb"
TranslationEnhancer::install! TranslationDictionary
```

Now, if I start the server in development environment, everything is ok during the first request. However, after that request, @dictionaries are suddenly nil. I have commented all other code in TranslationEnhancer, so I am absolutely sure the whole module must get reloaded every time I do a request.

I tried to move the module outside of the lib directory (moved it to lib_unloadable), then I tried:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.explicitly_unloadable_constants << "TranslationEnhancer"
```

but failed again. I have no idea how to solve this, please help.

Got Ruby 1.9.2 @ Rails 3.1.rc4.

EDIT: I know I could set the dictionaries as a constant. But I would like to use TranslationEnhancer as a library - so I could use it unchanged in a different project and install different Directories, such as:

```
TranslationEnhancer.install! EnglishDirectory, FrenchDirectory
```

These values won'd change during the runtime, they will just change project to project.

Comment: Well, it's a feature, not a bug :-) Couldn't resist, sorry for that.

Comment: Why dont you just define a constant inside an initalizer that way you would be able to access it by name all ofer the application? Do you need to change the value during the lifetime of the application?

Comment: you can define a constant as a hash and change it's content value whenever you need (still looking for a better solution)

Comment: what do you mean by `I store a value in a class variable inside of a module`. Is the module Mixin? or is it a module variable?

Comment: It is a module variable. The value won't change during the lifetime of the application but the module is a library so I have to give it the value from outside so it can stay independent and reusable. Couldn't I just remove this module from some list of automatically reloaded modules? It there anything like that?

Comment: what about adding `unloadable` in your module? I never tried that but could be a clue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved!

I realized that the whole application.rb and environment.rb files are reloaded along with all other files. The only thing that does not get reloaded are initializers (config/initializers/*). The solution was to move the initialization to application.rb.

Answer (score 0):

@dictionaries is not a "class variable". It is a "class-level instance variable".
Look here for a better explanation: [Class and instance variables](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/)

Try using @@dictionaries instead.

Comment: Interesting article, thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, it is unrelated to the problem. Everything reloads on every request, including class-level instance variables and class variables :(

Comment: Ah. that's weird. I know Rails has reloading of models to facilitate easier/dynamic changing of code on the fly (without requiring a server restart). There's an environment/config option that enables this. Perhaps you can test this stuff in development by turning that off. It'll mean you have to restart every time you make a code change... but that may be acceptable to you.

Comment: "config.cache_classes = false"

not sure if it'll help - but might be worth a try?